# Why does Spring JMS framework use MessageCreator?

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I having a difficult time understanding the pattern that Spring JMS uses for sending messages. The class JmsTemplate takes a MessageCreator as an argument. Like this:

```
JmsTemplate.send(MessageCreator messageCreator)
```

There is no option to pass a Message object directly. This seems very anti-Spring because MessageCreator cannot be a Singleton. If it was a singleton, it wouldn't be thread-safe because of this method:

```
MessageCreator.createMessage(Session session)
```

The createMessage method only takes a session object. So in order for this object to create a message, it would need to be initialized with some state, and if it has state then it can't be singleton.

So what is the point in forcing me to have a MessageCreator? Because in any real situation MyMessageCreator will always look like this:

```
public MyMessageCreator(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
    return session.createTextMessage(message);
}
```

Because generating the message will always require some beans or other dynamic values. Why do **some** of the message construction in this class if **all of it** can't be done?

And if the only reason is so that we have a reference to the Session object, then I'm sure there is a better way to access this instance from a spring bean (by injecting it, getting it from the template itself, or by using some factory method).

Am I missing something? Or is MessageCreator pointless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Session` is linked to your send operation, it's not a singleton. And you need to have access to this `Session` to be able to create a `javax.jms.Message`.

There is no way for you to pass a `javax.jms.Message` to `JmsTemplate` because then you would need the session first to create it and that session is actually managed internally by `JmsTemplate`.

You should do things the other way around. You should have a method that returns a `MessageCreator` instead of the `Message` you would like to build. That method can be placed in a Spring bean and can have whatever injection you need. And since it's a method of yours you can pass whatever dynamic value that you want.

That being said, being able to benefit from Spring 4.0's messaging abstraction (`org.springframework.messaging.Message`) is a great idea because it would allow you to build the message the way you want in a protocol-independent manner.

I have created [SPR-11772](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11772) for you.

Comment: Why would I want to use Session object, when Spring provides MessageConverter abstraction? Just can't think of any use case for this MessageCreator that can't be done with other constructs.

Comment: Not sure which `MessageConverter` abstraction you're thinking but the JMS one needs the session. And for an obvious reason, the JMS API needs you to pass the session when you create a `javax.jms.Message`.